# Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, addressables

I've recently integrated Play Asset Delivery as well as the Addressables PAD sample into my project, only to get this exception every time my game starts:

```
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   : AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$500(Unknown Source:0)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:126)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :      ... 9 more
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
12-04 11:06:43.130 32520 32638 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.FindClass (System.String name) [0x00000] in <00000
```

If anyone could help me resolve this issue then that'd be great. I'm current using Unity 2021.3.21f1 and Play Asset Delivery 1.8.2.

I've tried modifying the launcher Gradle template and main Gradle template to no avail. For the launcher template, I've added `implementation 'com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.1.0'` into the dependencies section. I've also tried deleting all resolved libraries and then resolving them again.